# Cell phone/DSLR invisible in Altap Salamander 3.06

Tags: windows-7, camera, mobile-phone

I am using [Altap Salamander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altap_Salamander) as my file manager, and I am satisfied with it. Except for the case when I connect my Xperia L (or any other phone) or my camera (Canon 700D) via USB.

I can see those devices in Windows' Explorer under portable devices. I can see them in Total commander under Drive overview, but they are invisible to Altap Salamander.

I think it is because they are not given a drive letter. In Explorer the address is shown as `Computer\Canon EOS 700D\SD\DCIM\`. In [Total Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Commander) it is `\\Canon EOS 700D\SD\DCIM\`.

Is there a way how to assign a drive letter to such a device, like it is assigned to USB flash drives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New phones and other devices use the MTP protocol to transfer files and no longer appear as a USB disk device.

This has the benefit that both the phone/device and computer can access the memory card within the device at the same time with minimal conflicts. This is a good thing as it means that the device does not have to unmount the memory card first and loose track of what is on it for some random amount of time.

What you need is to find a way to access MTP devices in Altap Salamander. Apparently a plugin was meant to be developed already, but it has so far failed to materialise: http://forum.altap.cz/viewtopic.php?t=31927